# Converting a UDP Payload -> Struct -> Long, Lat in decimal degree (12.41N, 2.40E) (im a junior < 1 year) c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, udp, latitude-longitude

First ever time asking a question on here so go easy on me if its not up to par.

Visual Studio.
C++.
UDP.

I receive a UDP payload which I store in a char buffer.
I have a struct which is byte-aligned to split the buffer into the elements of the struct.

I need to get the lon, lat from the struct and cout to console but it doesnt look correct.

When i wireshark the UDP payload i can see the lon, lat and i know the values it represents:
3FA24690119236AC -> 12.41890000 (N)
3FCBBE7C9C146695-> 2.04515000  (E)

The data type for the lon, lat im using is unsigned long long.

I cannot work out how to go from 3FCBBE7C9C146695 -> 12.41890000 bearing in mind its probably little-endian.

Could someone be so kind as to explain what I should be doing, in a <1 year juniors mindset and demonstrate with some code.

I understand you wont have the UPD payload.

This is my understanding of what I would like to see (if I even understand the process correctly).

```
char buffer[] = { '3F', 'A2', '46', '90', '11', '92', '36', 'AC'};
struct payload { unsigned long long lat; };

payload p;
std::memcpy(&p, buffer, sizeof(p));

.... convert to its dec degree

printf("Lat: %llu\n", p.lat);
```

Again I am a newbie and wish to learn!

Many thanks in advance, also let me know if I need to format my question better!

`p.lat = ntohll(p.lat);`
`p.lat = ntohd(p.lat);`

Tried these and changing the data type to double, long, int64, uint64 but I'm chasing my tail now.

More Info....

12.41250000°N 2.43520000°E is the output i want to see.

UDP payload only (**lat**, *lon* are the only parts of interest)

39000000000000000000000000030000006500000059ffffffffffffffff41d9205f3f80000000000001c0a801b7**3fcbbad397da94bd***3fa5c2db1fc191f8*000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017ae

Documentation states these (lat, lon) should be
8 byte double   (accepted values: -π/2 - &pi/2; (Radians)) for lat
8 byte double   (accepted values: -π - π (Radians) for lon

Now using `unsigned char arrays (UPD -> Struct)`

then

```
double result;
std::memcpy(&result, p.lat, sizeof(double));
std::cout << "Lat: " << result << std::endl;
```

gives: Lat: -4.74162e-12

Printing out the array:
3fa5c2db1fc191f8
so it seems the array hold the correct hex i see in wireshark.

Please do try and 'dumb it down' as I really would like to understand the issue i have and not just to solve it.

Thanks Again

Comment: `unsigned long long` is an integer, it can't hold decimal values. You want a floating-point type instead, either `float` (32 bits) or `double` (64 bits). Do you have any documentation for the UDP payload? It should tell you what data types the payload is actually using. Where is the data coming from, exactly?

Comment: there are a number of problems here, starting with the fact that you cannot create a char array and then try to put multiple chars per char (`'3F'` is two chars, if you want a hex byte, use the format `0x3F` ). I would also recommend unsigned chars (`uint8_t`) for buffers like that where you are getting binary data as you'll notice that even if you use the correct `0x` byte format, you still probably get compiler warnings. This is also not something easily solved without seeing one of those packets and knowing what its protocol is being used on top of UDP (for me at least)

Comment: It is also unclear if all 8 bytes you show from wireshark are being coverted to a float/double value or if it is for instance 4 bytes float, 4 bytes other information such as direction for each of those fields, so knowing the protocol is pretty important. I suspect this (nonstandard encoding) is the case if the values posted in your question are correct because neither of those hex values are close to the double values you say wireshark gives for them in either byte order

Comment: @DouglasB, i cannot disclose to much about the UDP and protocols sadly. I can provide the wireshark payload i can see,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clue1: RADIANS

Clue2: There's nothing stopping you trying the degrees and radians double to char[] conversion and seeing what it gives you.

It turns out that it converts the radians, rather than degrees version of the angle. On my PC at least you also have to reverse the order of bytes. (But I don't know how universal that is.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const double PI = 4.0 * atan( 1.0 );

double decode( unsigned char *buffer, int n )
{
   reverse( buffer, buffer + n);
   double result;
   memcpy( &result, buffer, n );
   return result * 180.0 / PI;
}

int main()
{
   const int N = sizeof( double );
   unsigned char buffer1[N] = { 0x3f, 0xcb, 0xba, 0xd3, 0x97, 0xda, 0x94, 0xbd };
   unsigned char buffer2[N] = { 0x3f, 0xa5, 0xc2, 0xdb, 0x1f, 0xc1, 0x91, 0xf8 };
   cout << "Latitude:  " << decode( buffer1, N ) << '\n';
   cout << "Longitude: " << decode( buffer2, N ) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Latitude:  12.4125
Longitude: 2.4352
```

Comment: perfect, could you please advise how you came to this conclusion a little more. For example this const double PI = 4.0 * atan( 1.0 );

Comment: Hello, @MC-spark, it's just a quick way of getting PI. (It follows from rearranging tan(PI/4)=1 and is still quite often used). You could just as well go and look up a high-precision numerical version if you prefer. Also, C++20 also has pi (and other famous mathematical constants) in the <numbers> header if you prefer.

Comment: thanks again, could you point me in the direction of how i can now convert these to x,y,z coords using WGS84, i though i had it nailed but its not showing as expected.

Comment: @MC-spark, I think that's really a separate question. If the earth were a perfect sphere then the coordinates would be x=r.cos(latitude)cos(longitude), y=r.cos(latitude)sin(longitude), z=r.sin(latitude). I'm afraid that I don't know how WGS84 deals with the ellipticity of the earth.